# How to get access token once authenticated via AWS Federated Identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I understand that we can get the Access Token when we authenticate via Cognito User Pools like this method:

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken())
```

Now, how do we get the Access Token when we use Federated Identities like Facebook, Google? Is it possible to get the access token? I am able to see Facebook token, but that is not AWS token right like in AWS User Pools.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to integrate the auth SDK as well located here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js

That would have you login with Facebook if Facebook is an identity provider for your user pool. A corresponding user is created in your user pool and the auth SDK saves that username and tokens in a local storage location (same location where the Cognito User Pools SDK that contains the authenticateUser method retrieves it from). By using getCurrentUser and getSession from the Cognito User Pools SDK you can retrieve that user and the session containing the tokens.

Comment: could you share an example ?